# Providing un-intrusive messages on an iPhone

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, dialog, message

This is kind of a silly question, but I cannot find the answer as I don't know the terms with which to search for it.

I am looking for a simple way of giving a 'status' message like 'Data updated' to the user without necessarily interrupting what he/she is doing (but have a option I guess in some instances to tab it an perform an action).

For example; some Apps give a rounded square semi-transparent with 'Lock screen/rotation' when an iPhone is rotated, I am look for something similar (or like the square box 'Build Complete in Xcode 4').

Is there an easy way of doing this?
Thanks a million in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

https://github.com/myell0w/MTStatusBarOverlay

MTStatusBarOverlay adds very subtle text to the phone's status bar. If you're looking for something a little more noticiable, try:

https://github.com/jdg/MBProgressHUD

Comment: looks nice, but does it pass Apple's guidelines?

Comment: MBProgressHUD is definitely OK. MTStatusBarOverlay should be fine, similar status-bar hiding techniques are used in Reeder, Evernote and Google Mobile App.

Answer (score 3):

As @kubi has pointed out, MTStatusBarOverlay is a good one, and I've passed Apple reviewer inspection with it.  *However* I just found something that looks fraking awesome...

[Tweetbot-Like Alert Panels (Blog)](http://blog.mugunthkumar.com/coding/ios-code-tweetbot-like-alertpanels/), and the repository is [MKInfoPanelDemo at Github](https://github.com/MugunthKumar/MKInfoPanelDemo).

Answer (score 1):

Create a view that shows your message nicely, add it to the window, and start a UIView animation which makes it fade away. In the animation ended handler (delegate or block) remove the view.